# How do I compare frequencies within and between locations in a time series evaluation?

Tags: time-series, multilevel-analysis

I am currently looking at the effect of predation in the temporal variation of colour morphs in a species of fish. In the experiment, frequency of each morph (two morphs) were assessed three times before fish from each tank was split in two other tanks, one with and another without a predator. Then, morph frequency was assessed three times in each of these tanks. To me it sounds as I could analyse the data with an hierarchical model, but I am not quite sure how i could do that for multiple measures for the period before and after fish were split in different tanks.

Would you guys know the statistical test I could potentially analyse my data set?

Thanks for your help,
Jonathas